# Insert more of one text delimiter - javascript

Tags: javascript

I want insert more of one text delimiter for filtering values for my table rows:
This is default code:

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable().yadcf([
{
        column_number: 1,
        text_data_delimiter: ",",
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
    },
```

in the above code text delimiter is a comma but i want insert also a hyphen with a space in front of and behind the hyphen:

```
text_data_delimiter: " - ",
```

I try write so

```
{
        column_number: 1,
        text_data_delimiter: ",",
        text_data_delimiter: " - ",
        filter_type: "auto_complete"
```

but javascript filters only by  `-` and not also `,`

Comment: It obviously takes the last value you gave. It is not that clear what do you want to do

Comment: Vorrei avere 2 text delimiter, sia la virgola e sia il trattino. I wish I had two text delimiter.

Comment: two delimiters in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use regex. To use `","` and `" - "`, this should work:

```
column_number: 1,
text_data_delimiter: /(\s-\s)|,/,
filter_type: "auto_complete"
```

**Do not add quotes**, it's not a string, it's a regular expression.

#### JS Fiddle

Comment: It works but if you type `domingo` for filter column called `Descrizione` you have twice values Placido Domingo..is possible remove duplicates updating javascript code, please? I update example, you can see problem here http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/10/

Comment: @user3520363 That's because you have multiple entries that contain this name. Unfortunately, I don't know how to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple delimiters are not officially supported by the `yadcf` plugin.

But it seems that you can abuse it a bit by passing it a regular expression.

So try

```
text_data_delimiter: /\b(?: - |,)\b/g
```

---

*It might break in future releases of the plugin though..*

Comment: i try to write `text_data_delimiter: "/\b(?: - |,)\b/g",` but don't work, look my example http://jsfiddle.net/chcLmmps/7/

Comment: @user3520363 no do not put quotes `"` around it.